# Example of modules over PID's

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules

From Advanced Modern Algebra (Rotman):

> **Definition** If $M$ is a finitely generated torsion $R$-module, where $R$ is a PID, and $$M= R/(c_1) \oplus R/(c_2) \oplus ... \oplus R/(c_t),$$ where $t \geq 1$ and $c_1 | c_2 | ... | c_t$, then the ideals $(c_1), (c_2), ... , (c_t)$ are called the ***invariant factors*** of $M$.

---

> **Corollary 8.20** If $M$ is a finitely generated torsion module over a PID $R$, then $$(c_t) = \{r \in R: rM=\{0\}\},$$ where $(c_t)$ is teh last ideal occuring in the decomposition of $M$ [in the definition].
>
> In particular, if $R=k[x]$, where $k$ is a field, then $c_t$ is the monic polynoial of least degree for which $c_tM=\{0\}$.

I understand how these work for abelain groups. Let $G = J(c_1) \oplus ... \oplus J(c_r),$ where $J(c_i)$ is a cyclic group of order $c_i$, and $c_1 | c_2 | ... |c_r$. Then, since $c_iJ(c_i) = 0$, (if we let $c_r = ac_i$ for some $a$) we have $c_rJ(c_i) = a(c_iJ(c_i)) = 0$. It also makes intuitive sense to me.

But when I think about modules, it kind of gets confusing. How can you annhilate a cylic module by multiplying it by a *polynomial*? In other words, I thought that it would be clearer in my head if I saw an example, so I tried to search the internet but couldn't really find anything useful. So I was wondering if anybody could give me an example (even if its a simple one), just so I can see how multiplying by a polynomial can annihilate a cyclic module.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the $k[x]$-module $k[x]/(x^2)$. Then multiplying by $x^2$ will annihilate the module.

I like the following example. If you have a finite dimensional complex vector space $V$ with a linear transformation $f\colon V\to V$, then you can have a structure of $k[x]$-module on $V$, where $x$ acts on $V$ via $f$. Then by the theorem you can decompose $V$ into the sum $V=V/(x-c_1)^{r_1}\oplus\dots\oplus V/(x-c_k)^{r_k}$. This decomposition is exactly the decomposition of $V$ into generalized eigenspaces $V_{c_i}$, where $V_{c_i}=\{v\in V\mid (f-c_i)^Nv=0\mbox{ for some N}\}$. So in this example the theorem gives you the Jordan Normal Form theorem.

Comment: Funny we even chose the same polynomial for the explict example. The link to Jodan Normal Form is nice.

Comment: Looking at this again there is nit-pick; the decomposition you mention does not really seem to correspond to the theorem, as in the theorem the polynomials form a chain of divisors whereas you gave the decomposition with polynomials that are powers of irreducble polynomials (corresponding to the situation of decomposing a cylcic group, or a finite abelain group, as cyclic groups of prime power order).

Comment: @quid Thanks, you are right! My mistake. It is endeed not the same decomposition. I was using the decomposition via elementary divisors, not invariant factors. But both decompositions are unique (up to permutations and mult.by units) and you can pass from one decomposition to the other easily.

Answer (score 1):

For a very explcit example $R= \mathbb{Q}[X]$, this is a PID, and let $M = \mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^2)$. You can alternatively think of this as $\{a + bX \colon a, b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ with component wise addition and the multiplciation by an element of $R$ so an arbitrary polynomial is given by 'multiply as polynomials and keep only constant and linear term'.

This module is cyclic (generated by $1$ or any non-zero constant). And multiplying by $X^2$ always  yields $0$.

There is nothing special about $X^2$ you can do the same with any polynomial.